# Drop/Create Azure Database On Build

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, sqlps

I'm setting up a post-git push trigger on an Azure web app that pulls in the latest web app build, and the latest database build and deletes/recreates the DB again from scratch using the latest database build.

I was hoping to achieve the drop/create part with the SQLPS module in PowerShell, and whilst it runs locally, this module isn't available when the script is hosted on Azure, and no one seems to have successfully uploaded binaries onto Azure to support the module.

What are my options? Surely there has to be a relatively simple way of creating a web-app trigger that can interact with an Azure-hosted server. What's the supported method of doing this?

Comment: dont think it is a stackoverflow question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulletproof way to DROP and CREATE a database under Continuous Integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463680/bulletproof-way-to-drop-and-create-a-database-under-continuous-integration)